# How to traverse a graph, which is changing in the same time?

Tags: concurrency, garbage-collection, thread-safety, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I have a graph, which can be concurrently modified. In other words, it is a thread-safe data structure, which allows to add or remove edges and vertices.

I cannot come up with the idea, how to traverse such a graph. It seems, in some cases it is impossible. For example, let's consider a linear tree (a-ka linked list). If new vertices are being added, and at the same time we traverse this graph, it is an endless procedure.

P.S. I have this graph, because of garbage collection, which I try to implement.

Comment: Get interested how *concurrent mark* is implemented in GCs - f.e. you can watch my [episode about .NET GC implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSHisrMt6-8).

Comment: Maybe, it’s helpful to read about [Tri-color marking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Tri-color_marking). It’s worth to keep in mind that unreachable objects will stay unreachable, no matter what the application does (as being unreachable implies the impossibility to access it), further, the creation of new objects will come to a stop for sure, in the worst case, when the gc truly can’t catch up with the allocation rate, the application has to stop and wait for the gc when the memory is exhausted.